# viewForFooterInSection not showing into the bottom of the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

viewForFooterInSection not showing into the bottom of the screen(uitableview).
here I am using UItableview.[image]

Note: in below screen vary bottom of the screen one more footer added.(white color view).
Redcolorview: footer (from below code)
blue color: table background color
white bottom:

Red color view I added programmatically, using below code:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
estimatedHeightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 44;
}
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"%f",tableView.frame.size.width);

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 44)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    UIButton *cancelButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 7, tableView.frame.size.width/2 - 60, 30)];
    [cancelButton setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cancelButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cancelButton setBackgroundColor:[ValidationsClass colorWithHexString:NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"pothysapp_label_text_backgroundcolor",@"ApplicationSettings",[NSBundle mainBundle], nil)]];
    [cancelButton addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(cancelDetails:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cancelButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Bold" size:15];
    cancelButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
    [view addSubview:cancelButton];

    UIButton *saveButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(tableView.frame.size.width/2 + 30, 7, tableView.frame.size.width/2 - 60, 30)];
    [saveButton setTitle:@"Save" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [saveButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [saveButton setBackgroundColor:[ValidationsClass colorWithHexString:NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"pothysapp_label_text_backgroundcolor",@"ApplicationSettings",[NSBundle mainBundle], nil)]];
    [saveButton addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(saveDetails:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    saveButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Roboto-Bold" size:15];
    saveButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
    [view addSubview:saveButton];

    return view;
}
```

Comment: footer of section will not appear on the bottom of table view section unless your section has sufficient cells to cover screen.

Comment: Check below link it might be useful to you https://stackoverflow.com/a/7238601/5184217

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead of returning your custom view in **viewForFooterInSection**.

Add your custom view to table footer in **ViewdidLoad**()

```
self.tableview.tableFooterView =//Your CustomView;
```

Comment: Thanks! But in other cases, viewForFooterInSection works, I cannot figure out why

Answer (score 0):

I removed estimatedHeightForFooterInSection and viewForFooterInSection.

Instead of this i added view in viewdidload:
`self.tableview.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, -20, 0);`

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 15, self.view.frame.size.width, 30)];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.tableview.tableFooterView = view;

UIButton *cancelButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 7, self.view.frame.size.width/2 - 60, 30)];
[cancelButton setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cancelButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[view addSubview:cancelButton];

UIButton *saveButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 + 30, 7, self.view.frame.size.width/2 - 60, 30)];
[saveButton setTitle:@"Save" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[saveButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[view addSubview:saveButton];
```